# Date format Issue In Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate

I used following code for compare two dates. But in spite of, I set the date format, I am not able to get date as per specified date format.

My code is as follow:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSString *g = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"EventDate"]];
NSLog(@"%@", g);
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *ed = [df dateFromString:g];
NSLog(@"%@\n %@", ed, today);
```

Output is :

```
04/09/2013
2013-04-08 18:30:00 +0000
2013-04-09 13:13:29 +0000
```

Comment: That is quite a good date. No error with those.

Comment: But i want Last two dates `ed & today` must be as per date format, not the IST date.

Comment: Whenever you print NSDate you will get in that format only. **Reformat to string** and print as per your requirement.

Comment: @user2243212 : remember to accept an answer if it solved your problem, or comment if you need more help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for this, your last log should be :

```
NSLog(@"%@\n%@", [df stringFromDate: ed], [df stringFromDate: today]);
```

That way, you will display your dates (`ed` and `today`) according to your `NSDateFormatter`.